# Getting Error in SOAP POST request using Apache CXF but curl works

Tags: java, apache, curl, https, cxf

I'm having a very strange problem. I'm trying to do a SOAP POST request over HTTPS. When I'm sending the request from my code, I'm getting HTTP 500 error. Now from the cxf log if I copy the same SOAP message(header and body) that I got error for and post it using a simple curl request it's working fine. Below is how I'm creating service class and other initialization

```
URL wsdlurl = SOAPWebServiceTransport.class.getClassLoader().
        getResource("my.wsdl");
OnlinePort service= new OnlinePortService(wsdlurl).getOnlinePortPort();
Client proxy = ClientProxy.getClient(service);

// Provides WS-Security
WSS4JOutInterceptor wss4jOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor();
wss4jOut.setProperty("action", "UsernameToken");
wss4jOut.setProperty("user", userName);
wss4jOut.setProperty("passwordType", "PasswordText");
wss4jOut.setProperty("password", password);
wss4jOut.setProperty(WSHandlerConstants.ADD_UT_ELEMENTS,
        WSConstants.NONCE_LN + " " + WSConstants.CREATED_LN);
wss4jOut.setProperty(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, ServerPasswordCallback.class.getName());

proxy.getEndpoint().getOutInterceptors().add(wss4jOut);
setConduitProperties((HTTPConduit) proxy.getConduit(),url);
```

In the set conduit method I'm ignoring the ssl check (for development env only) and setting some header.

```
TLSClientParameters tcp = new TLSClientParameters();
tcp.setDisableCNCheck(true);
// Creating Trust Manager
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
    new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
} };

tcp.setTrustManagers(trustAllCerts);
conduit.setTlsClientParameters(tcp);

HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
httpClientPolicy.setAccept("*/*");
httpClientPolicy.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
httpClientPolicy.setHost(url.split("/")[2]);
conduit.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

Any help would be highly appreciable.

```
Response-Code: 500
Encoding: ISO-8859-1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Headers: {connection=[close], content-type=[text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1],
          Date=[Mon, 15 Jun 2015 06:42:09 GMT], Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1],
          Set-Cookie=[JSESSIONID=FF0E4F5DCA42F700FFAC46BBD039FC20; Path=/; Secure],
          transfer-encoding=[chunked]}
Payload: 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

> <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
> charset=ISO-8859-1"/> <title>Error Page</title> </head> <body>Invalid
> Request </body> </html>


at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor.handleMessage(StaxInInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:797)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1618)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1491)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1399)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:188)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:646)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:533)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
 Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream:
```

**CURL Request**

curl -k --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction:" --data @soaprequest.xml https://url

[Curl log in verbose](http://pastebin.com/3pudPi3j) (ofcourse have changed some url port names0

**Error response from server**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error Page</title>
</head>
<body>Invalid Request
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So this is the client stack trace. Would you be able to know what happend on the server side. My assumption is that some authentication attempt went wrong and the server issued a HTML response. In `curl` it does not matter, from CXF point of view : "Response was of unexpected text/html" - indicates a server side issue.

Comment: No its not possible for us to see what's happening in the server side.Yeah cxf is failing because its receiving a html response instead of soap based xml but that I'm getting because of some error or validation exception at server side I guess.Surprisingly the same soap request with almost same http header is working with curl.

Comment: I bet your Content-Type header is being overwritten before the request is made, can you inspect the Post request header as they are sent from the application?

Comment: @JacobMargason  its sending  'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8' I checked it

Comment: I see that you are setting a SOAPAction header in your curl request, I don't see that header being set in your JAVA. Could that be the problem? If you can, I would try and capture the complete POST requests from both curl and JAVA and compare them. The problem likely lies in the headers.

Comment: @JacobMargason I tried adding SOAPAction header as well got the same result. The curl also works without SOAPAction.

Comment: Is the http proxy used in both cases?

Comment: @AntonK.  We have a proxy server (haproxy) from which the request go to the client end and both the request (curl and java) goes through the same.

Comment: Are you sure that your WSDL URL used in the client is the right URL?

Comment: @vzamanillo yes its the right url as I'm getting response in HTML (which is send by the server on some soap error)

Comment: And what the error is? the trace is not complete.

Comment: @vzamanillo the problem is its getting some error in server and the server sends back html due to this.Now my client is expecting xml and when it tries to parse it as xml,thus it gives this error. Whats happening in the server is not known to us and we are not able to understand why we are getting this as the same data in curl is passing.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but what is the HTML content returned by the server? it is really empty?

Comment: @vzamanillo added error response

Comment: Can you not capture and show us the complete POST request that is generated by your Java? I feel strongly that the problem is somewhere in the request headers.

Comment: @JacobMargason can't show the complete post request due to confidentiality issue. The SOAP message and headers are fine as I copied it from cxf log and send it using curl. There might be something wrong with Https header which is getting difficult to figure out. That's why I posted the code for proxy and httpconduit.

Comment: As you seem to mention, the problem is on server side as it does not receive the same request from the curl-client and the java-CXF-client. Does the message sent by both client contains the same Soap's headers? (user, password, passwordType etc...). As Jacob said, it would be a good thing to capture the http sent by both cxf and curl with a tool like TcpMon, and check the differences between both messages (but not really sure if it is possible as they may be encrypted by SSL).

Comment: @FrancoisGergaud the soap header and message is exactly same as I copied it from cxf log and send it using curl. Might be some issue with https which is getting difficult to track as the message is encrypted by SSL

Comment: may you should execute curl with -v to let us see what the server actually returns with its headers

Comment: @Zarathustra  http://pastebin.com/3pudPi3j  curl log in verbose added it in the question as well.

Comment: I think this may be due to the SSL handshake failing, I bet you it's a return value of 19 (self signed etc..) I had a similar problem recently. Use openssl and specify the same CA certs that you specify in the code. ""openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -showcerts -CApath /path/ssl/certs -CAfile /path/ssl/blah.pem < /dev/null | less"" If the Verify return code is anything but zero then this is likely the culprit. What fixed this for me was not specifying the SSL CA's in the application configuration and so it defaulted to the system trusted root certs which worked.

Comment: Maybe there is nothing common with your problem, but I think that you should use another date format when sending messages - yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSZ :)

Comment: I just noticed that your curl used `charset=UTF-8` but when you do it from your code, it is going out as `charset=ISO-8859-1`. Could that be an issue?

Comment: did you solve this issue? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 2):

SOAP works on xml and I  can see the you have the following error

`Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream:`

Which is saying that your response is coming in HTML,
`Response-Code: 500
Encoding: ISO-8859-1
Content-Type: text/html;chars`

So there might be a problem with your WebService try using SOAP UI

also this link will be quite helpful talks about the same issue.
https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/27468/web-service-consumer-response-was-of-unexpected-te.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access the log on the server you can try to check if your code request and the curl request are different.

To do that you can sniff the http request with a sniffer like [tcpmon](https://code.google.com/p/tcpmon/).

Tcpmon operates as a proxy between your client and the server. It intercepts all requests and print the details of each request and response.

Comment: Soap header and message is exactly same as I copied it from cxf log and send it using curl. Might be some issue with https which is getting difficult to track as the message is encrypted using SSL

Answer (score 0):

The turnaround was to use core java HttpURLConnection to achieve this.

A method something like this helped the cause ad post a webservice call without any framework.:

```
public HttpURLConnection getHttpConn(String webservice_url) throws IOException {
URL endpoint = new URL(webservice_url);
URLConnection connection = endpoint.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((getUsername()+":"+getPassword()).getBytes());
httpConn.setRequestMethod(getRequestMethod());
httpConn.setRequestProperty(HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING, getAccept_Encoding());
httpConn.setRequestProperty(HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE, getContentType());
httpConn.setRequestProperty(getContent_Length(), getContent_Length());
httpConn.setRequestProperty(HTTP_HOST, getHost());
httpConn.setRequestProperty(getConnection(), getConnection());
httpConn.setRequestProperty(HTTP_COOKIE2, getCookie2());
httpConn.setRequestProperty(HTTP_COOKIE, getCookie());
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+new String(encodedBytes));
httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
httpConn.setDoInput(true);
return httpConn;
}
```

Ensure to configure the http client in the CXF config file (cxf.xml).

As documented in Apache CXF document:

1.Add the http-conduit namespace and xsd:

```
<beans ...
       xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
       ...
       xsi:schemaLocation="...
           http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
           http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
       ...">
```

2.Add the http-conduit tag/element and set the RecieveTimeout/ConnectionTimeout to 180000ms:

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
      <http-conf:client 
                      ConnectionTimeout="300000"
                      ReceiveTimeout="300000"/>       
</http-conf:conduit>
```

Comment: Already tried with HttpURLConnection and some other framework didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

try using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) as a proxy and compare both requests. there must be a difference either in the headers or in the request body.

Fiddler is also capable of decoding TLS.

good luck to anyone..

Answer (score 0):

Check the WSDL URL.

URL has to be given till ?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

I've faced problem similar to yours recently. I've just added 2 artifacts into dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```